# How to Scrape href from Webpage (done it before but does not work for one website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape the links from certain div class (*class="card-img-block"*) of the following website : https://milled.com/OneKingsLane

I have managed to do this before on many different websites with the following method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
html = 'https://milled.com/OneKingsLane'
req = session.get(html)
bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

link_box = bs.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'card-img-block'})

for links in link_box:
    print(links['href'])
```

But for some reason when I use the same method I get the following error:

```
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Has anyone got an idea how I can scrape the URL from that div class?

Thanks :)

Comment: what happens if you just print `links`

Comment: it just prints our the whole div: <div class="card-img-block">
<a href="/OneKingsLane/a-breath-of-fresh-air-ovfl6TaVfcbrw3FX">
<picture>
<img alt="A breath of fresh air..." class="card-img lazyload" data-slug="a-breath-of-fresh-air-ovfl6TaVfcbrw3FX" data-src="https://images.milled.com/2019-12-12/AukOprAeuB5n4Rqd/c@2x.jpg"/>
</picture>
</a>
</div>

Comment: search for `'a'` within that `div` instead

Comment: I have tried that before, but it will either print nothing, or if I do the following  link_box = bs.find_all('a')   it will print out all links from the page, but I only need links from that specific div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `a` tag inside each `links` element:

```
for links in link_box:
    print(links.a['href'])
```

Comment: Amazing, quite an easy fix! Thank you very much - this has worked for me.